# Running oracle script as oracle user from a shell script that runs as root

Tags: sql, linux, shell, unix

I have a shell script that runs as root. I want the script to switch to oracle user, run sqlplus and run some `.sql` files.
I am trying to followung :

```
su - oracle << -EOF1  2>&1
        sqlplus $user/$password << -EOF2
                @oracle.sql;
                @quartz.sql;
        EOF2
EOF1
```

first of all i get `stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device` what does it mean ?

second, can someone explain to me how the redirect (should) work in this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if [ "$(id -un)" -eq "root" ]; then
    exec su - oracle -c $0
fi

sqlplus <<EOF
blablabla
EOF
```

If your script potentially takes arguments, the solution will differ.

What this does it checking whether the user running is currently root. If so, it re-executes the script (`$0`) as user `oracle` instead.

But BTW, why does the script run as root in the first place?

Comment: i agree running the script as root is a very bad practice, but i have no choice since the infrastructure that runs the script is running as root. Changing it is not my call

Comment: so what does your solution do exactly ?

Comment: I see. nice trick, unfortunately, there are some parts of the script that i need to be running as root (this is not the whole script, there are other parts). therefore i have to use the EOF block structure. my scrip could also have arguments as well

Comment: Make the Oracle specific parts run in another script which you invoke like the above?

Comment: Also, please note that heredoc markers **MUST** be at the beginning of line

Answer (score 0):

su - oracle -c " echo 'select 1 from dual;
select 2 from dual;'| sqlpus / as sysdba "

if contain ' using following
su - oracle -c " echo \"select 1 from dual;
select 2 from dual;\" | sqlpus / as sysdba "